# Remember referer parameters over 2 steps

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I am accessing an attachments edit page from different controllers (projects, task_groups or tasks). When I submit the form inside the attachments, $this->referer() is set to the attachments edit page as that's where the request was made from, and I want to go back where the edit page was called. How can I save referer parameters over 2 steps? (Maybe manually apply those parameters when the attachments edit action is called the first time?)

Comment: You can't. Use session instead.

Comment: Or pass them as query string: `?ref=URL`. This has the advantage that it would work with multiple browser tabs open. Session based approaches overwrite each other usually causing a mess :)

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on this, I try to pass `'ref' => $this->here` but it says Not Found... what should I do for that string to be read as variable and not part of the url?